# jQuery tabs: creating tabs from div and li cutom format not the example way

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, format

I'm trying to create some tabs with **Jquery**, J**query UI tabs**,  from this format that **Drupal** is ouputing me...

I have several options to do the output, but this is the one I have selected, however NONE are resembles the one from the example given in the demo page...
Maybe I can use the methods from UI tabs addtab or something to enforce tab creation with this format?

Can anyone help me acomplish that?

Here's my code:

```
<div class="view-content">
    <div class="item-list">
      <h3>La base</h3>

      <ul>
        <li class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
          <div class="views-field-field-imagen-miniatura-fid">
            <span class="field-content"><img height="57" width="67" class=
            "imagecache imagecache-lo_mas_leido_54_46 imagecache-default imagecache-lo_mas_leido_54_46_default"
            title="" alt="" src=
            "/sites/default/files/imagecache/lo_mas_leido_54_46/para_gustos_macetas.jpg" /></span>
          </div>

          <div class="views-field-title">
            <span class="field-content"><a href="/huerto-urbano/para-gustos-macetas">Para
            gustos, macetas</a></span>
          </div>

          <div class="views-field-teaser">
            <span class="field-content">Cada planta es un universo y tiene sus
            particularidades y caprichos pero, para hacernos una idea...</span>
          </div>

          <div class="views-field-view-node">
            <span class="field-content"><a href="/huerto-urbano/para-gustos-macetas">Leer
            m&Atilde;&iexcl;s</a></span>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even">
          <div class="views-field-field-imagen-miniatura-fid">
            <span class="field-content"><img height="57" width="67" class=
            "imagecache imagecache-lo_mas_leido_54_46 imagecache-default imagecache-lo_mas_leido_54_46_default"
            title="" alt="" src=
            "/sites/default/files/imagecache/lo_mas_leido_54_46/la_mesa_de_cultivo_ideal_0.jpg" /></span>
          </div>

          <div class="views-field-title">
            <span class="field-content"><a href=
            "/huerto-urbano/la-mesa-de-cultivo-ideal">La mesa de cultivo ideal</a></span>
          </div>

          <div class="views-field-teaser">
            <span class="field-content">Hace ya tiempo que la tendencia del Huerto Urbano
            est&Atilde;&iexcl; arraigando en las ciudades. Ante este nuevo...</span>
          </div>

          <div class="views-field-view-node">
            <span class="field-content"><a href=
            "/huerto-urbano/la-mesa-de-cultivo-ideal">Leer m&Atilde;&iexcl;s</a></span>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li class="views-row views-row-3 views-row-odd">
          <div class="views-field-field-imagen-miniatura-fid">
            <span class="field-content"><img height="57" width="67" class=
            "imagecache imagecache-lo_mas_leido_54_46 imagecache-default imagecache-lo_mas_leido_54_46_default"
            title="" alt="" src=
            "/sites/default/files/imagecache/lo_mas_leido_54_46/ojo_que_plantamos_1.jpg" /></span>
          </div>

          <div class="views-field-title">
            <span class="field-content"><a href=
            "/huerto-urbano/%C2%A1ojo-que-plantamos">&Acirc;&iexcl;Ojo, que
            plantamos!</a></span>
          </div>

          <div class="views-field-teaser">
            <span class="field-content">Al crear, mantener y disfrutar de nuestro huerto
            urbano debemos tener en cuenta ciertas medidas de...</span>
          </div>

          <div class="views-field-view-node">
            <span class="field-content"><a href=
            "/huerto-urbano/%C2%A1ojo-que-plantamos">Leer m&Atilde;&iexcl;s</a></span>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li class="views-row views-row-4 views-row-even views-row-last">
          <div class="views-field-field-imagen-miniatura-fid">
            <span class="field-content"><img height="57" width="67" class=
            "imagecache imagecache-lo_mas_leido_54_46 imagecache-default imagecache-lo_mas_leido_54_46_default"
            title="" alt="" src=
            "/sites/default/files/imagecache/lo_mas_leido_54_46/comprar_una_planta_3.jpg" /></span>
          </div>

          <div class="views-field-title">
            <span class="field-content"><a href=
            "/huerto-urbano/comprar-una-planta">Comprar una planta</a></span>
          </div>

          <div class="views-field-teaser">
            <span class="field-content">Podemos decidir entre comprar las semillas, la
            planta joven o la pl&Atilde;&iexcl;ntula (la planta peque&Atilde;&plusmn;a).
            Para...</span>
          </div>

          <div class="views-field-view-node">
            <span class="field-content"><a href="/huerto-urbano/comprar-una-planta">Leer
            m&Atilde;&iexcl;s</a></span>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="item-list">
      <h3>Extras</h3>

      <ul>
        <li class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first views-row-last">
          <div class="views-field-field-imagen-miniatura-fid">
            <span class="field-content"><img height="57" width="67" class=
            "imagecache imagecache-lo_mas_leido_54_46 imagecache-default imagecache-lo_mas_leido_54_46_default"
            title="" alt="" src=
            "/sites/default/files/imagecache/lo_mas_leido_54_46/como_identificar_una_planta_3.jpg" /></span>
          </div>

          <div class="views-field-title">
            <span class="field-content"><a href=
            "/huerto-urbano/como-identificar-una-planta">C&Atilde;&sup3;mo identificar
            una planta</a></span>
          </div>

          <div class="views-field-teaser">
            <span class="field-content">&Acirc;&iquest;En qu&Atilde;&copy; fijarse para
            identificar una planta, recordarla o describirla?
            &Acirc;&iquest;Cu&Atilde;&iexcl;les son...</span>
          </div>

          <div class="views-field-view-node">
            <span class="field-content"><a href=
            "/huerto-urbano/como-identificar-una-planta">Leer
            m&Atilde;&iexcl;s</a></span>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here's the jquery demos example:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>

      <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>

      <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tabs-1">
      <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur
      nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper
      ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean
      tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis
      orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie
      erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt
      interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-2">
      <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut
      pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla,
      massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut
      dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit
      aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis.
      Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla.
      Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus
      pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel
      felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-3">
      <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam
      vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem
      eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent
      per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim
      commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur
      lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>

      <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna.
      Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent
      blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra
      blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam
      scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi
      lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu
      tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus.
      Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: How exactly do you want to split that into tabs? Which part of your output must go into which tab?

Comment: La base and Extras are the tabs, and what follows are the contents (they're marked within a UL )

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to adjust the output to be more like the example. From a semantics point of view it is more sound and it has better fallback as in the example, if JavaScript fails to work, the list items provide bookmark-links to the content sections.

To see this in action, remove the .tabs() call from the example page and click the links - it is perfect functionality in the absence of the JavaScript working.

Comment: the problem is that doesn't matter what output i choose from drupal , it doesn't resemble the example, i can choose from  Bulk, Grid
 HTML List,Table, Unformatted still I don't know how to define custom presets, I think it's embeded somehow in drupal

Comment: Have you seen the Drupal layout for jQuery UI Tabs? http://drupal.org/project/tabs